# Does the complex function $f(z)$ have to be bounded on $|z|<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Take the complex function $f(z)$ =$ \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} z^n$ = $\frac{1}{1-z}$

I'm trying to make an argument to say that this function is bounded in the disc $|z|<1$. Originally I thought it should be true but I'm not sure if I'm actually able to prove this.

So firstly I looked at the fact that Cauchy-Hadamard guarantees absolute convergence for all z in the interior of the disc $|z|=1$. Therefore we know that $|f(z)|$= $ |\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} z^n|$ $\leq$ $ \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} |z|^n$ =$\frac{1}{1-|z|}$

The last expression can be made arbitrarily large since $|z|<1$ so that means that the fraction will tend to infinity, making it unbounded. Is this wrong? Did I miss something?

Are all complex functions represented by a Taylor Series with a finite radius of convergence unbounded on the interior of the disc of convergence?

Comment: $1/(1-z)$ is certainly not bounded for $\lvert z \rvert < 1$. Just think about it on the real line -- it has a vertical asymptote at $1$!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Of course! that makes sense thank you! Do you think this result generalizes to other complex Taylor series with finite radii of convergence?

Comment: In general, the radius of convergence of a complex taylor series is the distance to the nearest pole. So yes, if you have a finite radius of convergence, the taylor series cannot be bounded in the corresponding open disk (because it approaches $\infty$ as you approach the pole)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n/n^2$ has convergence radius $1$ and is bounded in $|z| < 1$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk thank you very much this was very helpful

Comment: @MartinR Well then this is embarrassing! I should relearn my complex analysis; thanks for the correction. This works for meromorphic functions, though, right?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: Yes, if $f$ is meromorphic in $\Bbb C$ then the radius of convergence of its power series at a point $z_0$ is the distance to the nearest pole.

Comment: @MartinR thank you!

Comment: it seems the issue with $\sum_1^\infty z^n/n^2$ is needing a branch cut at $z=1$ instead

Comment: @diracdeltafunc: To be more specific, if we assume that $f$ is defined on its "natural" domain, meaning that we don't artificially restrict the domain, then in a handwavey way, the radius of convergence tells us the distance to the closest boundary point of the domain. This can be the closest pole, but it could also be an essential singularity, or just the plain old boundary of the domain (the unit circle for a function defined on the unit disc, for instance). Only poles guarantee unboundedness in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A power series $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ with finite convergence radius $R> 0$ can be bounded or unbounded on $B_R(0)$. For example:

- $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}z^n$ is has convergence radius $1$ and is bounded on $B_1(0)$.
- $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n$ is has convergence radius $1$ and is unbounded on $B_1(0)$.

Some (necessary, but not sufficient) criteria are:

- If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| R^n < \infty $ then $f$ is bounded on $B_R(0)$.
- If all $a_n$ are non-negative real numbers and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n R^n = \infty $ then $f$ is unbounded on $B_R(0)$, that is a consequence of [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).

Comment: This was very helpful thank you!